# C winsock function to send all message data

Tags: c, winsock, winsock2, windows-socket-api

I'm writing a server in `c` using WSA that will handle multiple clients. The protocol is something I defined on my own, and the part I'm having trouble with is how to make sure the whole message is actually being sent to the client.

I `send` my message once, and than I check how many bytes where actually transferred. Then, if not, I `send` again, and as the length of the data that I will now send I use `unsentBytes` (see in code).
My problem is that when I try to send the extra bytes that weren't sent, I am currently sending again the entire message. How can I send only the remaining part of the message?

I know I can send only 1 char at a time, and stop recieving on the client side when I get to the end of the message, but I think I can do it like this as well and that it's better.

Is this the right logic to use?

```
int send_msg(SOCKET s, char *msg, int msg_len)
{
    int unsentBytes = msg_len;
    int bytesResult = send(s, msg, msg_len, SEND_FLAGS);
    unsentBytes -= bytesResult;
    while (unsentBytes != 0)
    {
        bytesResult = send(s, msg, unsentBytes, SEND_FLAGS); // ### msg is the problem
        unsentBytes -= bytesResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to keep the value of `msg` (as is the case in the posted code) you could just say `msg += bytesResult;` after each send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's working code from one of my own projects. Note `data + count` to offset into the data.

```
int sendall(int sd, char *data, int length) {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < length) {
        int n = send(sd, data + count, length, 0);
        if (n == -1) {
            return -1;
        }
        count += n;
        length -= n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When using this code, and in a similar one for recieving - shouldn't I handle the options that I recieved/sent 0 bytes?

Comment: If `send` returns zero, it will just try again.

Comment: Got it. So when -1 is returned, what exactly does it mean?

Comment: It means an error occurred. Possible errors are listed on this page: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/send.html